# Force UpdatePanel to reload from master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a dropdown menu in my master page and on its `SelectedIndexChanged` event, I want it to reload the content page's data. I have the content of the content page wrapped in an `UpdatePanel` so that I can do this in my master page's code behind:

```
Protected Sub ddlMyDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlMyDropdown.SelectedIndexChanged
    Session("NewVal") = ddlMyDropdown.SelectedValue
    upMyUpdatePanel.Update()
End Sub
```

Then in the content page I use the value set by the dropdown and display it to the screen:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    lblMyLabel.Text = Session("NewVal")
End Sub
```

The problem is that when `upMyUpdatePanel` updates, it's a step behind, meaning it reflects the value of `ddlMyDropdown` from one `SelectedIndexChanged` event before this one. I believe this is because the content page's `Page_Load` event is firing before the master page's `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

**How do I update the content page's content when a new value is selected from the master page's dropdown?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @wazz would have solved my problem if I didn't need the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to fire *before* the code runs in my content page.

I solved my issue by moving my content page's `Page_Load` code into the `Page_PreRender` so that it fires after the `SelectedIndexChanged` from the master page. Probably isn't ideal but it worked nicely.

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    'Do stuff...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to do everything from the content page.

All you would need on the content page is (C#):

```
// find the ddl on the master page.
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Page.Master.FindControl("DropDownList1");
// set the label's text.
Label1.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

You don't have to set the session data.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I could access master page controls from a content page. I'm going to try it out before accepting your answer but this should solve my problem.

Comment: This solves the simplified version of my problem that I wrote for the OP but my `SelectedIndexChanged` event has some code in it that needs to fire before the content page updates. So my original question is still unanswered: How do I update the content page's content after the `SelectedIndexChanged` event? I'll edit the OP to better describe my problem.